# Set state if the array exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to simply set a state if the data from the server exists.

```
const [names, setNames] = useState([...details?.names])
```

The details object is in the props and is set from the database. `details.names` is an array from the server. This works when the details.names object exists but I am having troubles if the names doesnt exist in the details object. If thats the case, setNames to an empty array.

Comment: const [names, setNames] = useState([...details?.names || []])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
const [names, setNames] = useState(details?.names ? [...details?.names] ?? [])
```

if `details?.names` is an array the only thing needed is this:

```
const [names, setNames] = useState(details?.names ?? [])
```

So basically use the Nullish coalescing operator, read more about that here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: Do you mean to use : in the first one?

Comment: Yes, the extension to get the extension work should be `.svelte`. Try to change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `useEffect` hook to detect a change in the `details` variable and trigger a state update:

```
const [names, setNames] = useState([])
    
useEffect(() => {
    if (details?.names) {
        setNames(details.names)
    }
}, [details])
```